# Hal+json viewer in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, hal-json

The [Firefox JSON Viewer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/JSON_viewer) shows up whenever the type is "application/json", but prompts for file download when given "application/hal+json". This used to be avoidable by just using the [JSON View](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/jsonview/) extension - but that is not currently supported in Quantum.

Is there anything I can do to have Firefox render hal+json?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself - use https://github.com/clemstoquart/webextension-json-mime-type to modify hal+json to be just json, so that the standard json formatter can be used.